# Save and apply button isn't working in configure system Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I'm facing issue in saving/applying configuration in jenkins (Manage jenkins ---> configure system).

Neither I get an error nor warning. Does anyone face this issue before? If yes then what is the solution to fix this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You do not provide sufficient details, but likely affected by [tables-to-divs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/views/table-to-div-migration/) issue/[JENKINS-56109](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-56109). Read that and follow the steps outlined.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue today . Please share solution if you fixed this issue

Comment: @IanW Tables to divs only affect version  2.264 (weekly) and 2.277.1 (LTS) if I am not wrong. In my case I am using Jenkins 2.289.1.2 version.

Comment: No, any incompatible older plugins listed will contain breaking html once core is 2.277.1+. Pligins must be upgraded to a patched version or removed/disabled. Follow the procedures to check.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue , version: 2.332.3

Comment: Hi All, the issue was related to plugin.  I removed all the deprecated/incompatible plugins  to solve this issue.